# Map object is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, jsonresponse

This happens when returning a `JSONResponse`, which was added in Django 1.7. and is a wrapper around `json.dumps`. However, in this case it results in an error. I'm sure the data is correct and can be serialized to JSON through Python shell.

What is the right way to serialize the data to JSON?

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from collections import OrderedDict

data = OrderedDict([('doc', '546546545'), ('order', '98745'), ('nothing', '0.0')])

return JsonResponse(data) # doesn't work, JSONRenderer().render(data) works
```

Results in this error:

```
<map object at 0x7fa3435f3048> is not JSON serializable
```

`print(data)` gives:

`OrderedDict([('doc', '546546545'), ('order', '98745'), ('nothing', '0.0')])`

Comment: Is `OrderedDict` you gave just an example data or the actual data you are getting the error with ?

Comment: That's the thing, I omitted some data that were causing the error.

Comment: What is `<map object at 0x7...>` doing in your code ?

Comment: I removed some parts for simplification, now it's expanded.

Comment: Would you mind printing `headers_prepared`?

Comment: `headers_prepared` added to the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96502/discussion-between-peter-gerhat-and-yash-mehrotra).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`map()` in Python 3 is a generator function, which is not serializeable in JSON. You can make it serializeable by converting it to a list:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from collections import OrderedDict

def order(request):    
    bunch = OrderSerializer(Order.objects.all(), many=True)
    headers = bunch.data[0].keys()
    # consume the generator and convert it to a list here
    headers_prepared = list(map(lambda x: {'data': x} , headers))
    ordered_all = (('columns', headers_prepared), ('lines', bunch.data))
    data = OrderedDict(ordered_all)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 16):

if someone come across this problme when using  map(),you can try using   list(map())    to solve this problem.